# Does this Hamiltonian have point spectrum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, operators, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

Consider such a Hamiltonian

$$  H = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} - F x + V(x) ,$$

with $F$ being some constant, and $V(x)= V(x+L)$ being some periodic potential.

Does this Hamiltonian have point spectrum? Or only essential spectrum?

Actually, a more basic question------is it self-adjoint?

Comment: It does not have the aspect of a self-adjoint operator (it is unbounded from below, and there are not much informations on $V$). If it was something like $-\Delta + F\lvert x \rvert + V(x)$ with $F\in \mathbb{R}$ (also negative) and $V$ bounded from below and locally square integrable then it would be self-adjoint by a theorem of Kato. This operator I just wrote is a good candidate also to point spectrum, since it has confining potential that goes to infinity when $\lvert x\rvert\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, $F$ can only be positive.

Comment: Suppose $V $ is a continuous function. Of course, to make the problem not so trivial, we need to have the unbounded potential $F x $.

Comment: A $V$ real, continuous and periodic gives no problems since it is actually bounded; but $Fx$ is not so good (without the absolute value); nevertheless, it may be self-adjoint by means of the corollary of Faris-Lavine theorem (theorem X.38 on Reed-Simon vol.2). You may only check that $\exists c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $cx^2+Fx +d\geq 0$ (and I would say that always exist, it is sufficient to complete the square). For the point spectrum however, without absolute value on $x$ I doubt you have it...